# JavaScript .click on DIV not working, why?

Tags: javascript, html, google-contacts-api

I'm doing an app using JavaScript to collect contacts from [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/?cplus=0#contacts). What I need to do is navigate to this site, click on a DIV and extract the HTML source.

Problem is, when I manually click on the DIV, the website has the expected behaviour. But when I call `click` on the same DIV programatically, nothing happens.

Here is the DIV in question :

```
<div id=":se" class="tk3N6e-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe Ycq2Ve tk3N6e-LgbsSe-roVxwc tk3N6e-LgbsSe-n2to0e tk3N6e-LgbsSe-vhaaFf-LK5yu ipG21e" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Next" aria-label="Next" style="user-select: none;">
<span class="Fj0vqf" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
<img class="P1rG1b tk3N6e-LgbsSe-RJLb9c" src="images/cleardot.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

To achieve the task, I'm using this JS :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tk3N6e-LgbsSe')[7].click();
```

Although the selector above return the correct node, when I call `.click()`, nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Below is the site image with the DIV in question highlighted:

[image]

Comment: where do you have defined your `click` event? can you provide an example?

Comment: It's not my event, it's the event on Google Contacts : https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/?cplus=0#contacts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following worked for me, had to do a mouseup after a mousedown.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tk3N6e-LgbsSe')[7].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'))
document.getElementsByClassName('tk3N6e-LgbsSe')[7].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup'))
```

Comment: Well, this is @epascarello s answer and 50+ contacts to play with! Glad that your problem is solved

Comment: Thank you.  Your code just ended a 2 day search....

Answer (score 3):

The click is bound to the TR element.

```
document.querySelectorAll("tr.K9ln3e")[4].click()
```

And than I saw that it is not the person you are clicking on, but the arrow. Funny thing is I do not have enough contacts in gmail to have the arrow so I can only assume this will work

```
var dv = document.getElementsByClassName('tk3N6e-LgbsSe')[7]
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});
dv.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: Thanks but this command would click in a contact, not on the 'Next' div ; please see the image in the question

Comment: I realized that when I went and swapped out your class to see what you were selecting. Looks like it is a mousedown and not a click bound to it when you inspect the element in the event listeners in chrome.

Comment: Is there a way to call a mousedown event via JS ?

Comment: Maybe the listener is not attached to the DIV ?

Comment: If you have more than 50, try changing items per page in settings.

Comment: @sabithpocker That would be a solution, but i'm trying to understand why the JS method won't work

Comment: @delphirules That suggestion was for epascarello as he mentioned he doesn't have enough contacts to check it.

Comment: @sabithpocker Ah, ok understood ;)